# Strange operation, Handler still call after application finish

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler

I create a simple application which load a list of category from the internet then load to UI...On the onCreate I create a thread to fetch information from internet, then show to the UI... I use interface to communate between activity with the thread class. The problem is when I press back to finish application, I saw that the thread still run and it still fire the the interface...

My activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("dj", "On Create!");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        //Load category list
        DjModel.getInstance(this).doDownloadCategoryList();
        //Show dialog loading
        showLoadingDialog();
}
//The listener implement
@Override
public void onGetListCategoryDone(List<Category> list) {
    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            mDrawerLayout);
    //Dismiss dialog
    closeLoadingDialog();
    //Start service it wasn't
    if(mDownloadIntent == null){
        mDownloadIntent =  new Intent(this, DjVipDownloadService.class);
        bindService(mDownloadIntent, mDownloadServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        startService(mDownloadIntent);
    }
}
```

My DjModel:

```
public class DjModel {


private static DjModel _model;
private final int MESSAGE_NOTIFY_GET_TRACKS_DONE = 1;
private final int MESSAGE_NOTIFY_GET_CATEGORY_DONE = 2;

public static DjModel getInstance(OnModelTaskDone callback){
    if(_model == null){
        _model = new DjModel(callback);
        _model.mListTrack = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    if(callback != null){
        _model.mOnModelTaskDone = callback;
    }
    return _model;
}
public void doDownloadCategoryList(){
    Thread thread = new Thread(new GetCategoryTask());
    thread.start();
}
private class GetCategoryTask implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        List<Category> list = new ArrayList<Category>();
        String json = Utils.getContentFromURL(Common.API_PLATFORM + Common.API_CATEGORY_LIST);
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            //Get result
            int result = jsonObject.getInt("result");
            if(result == 1){//Success
                //Parse datas
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    //Pull the data
                    long id = data.getLong("id");
                    String name = data.getString("name");
                    //Create category
                    Category category = new Category();
                    category.setID(String.valueOf(id));
                    category.setName(name);
                    list.add(category);
                }
            }else{

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Set to global data
        DjModel.getInstance(null).setListCategory(list);
        mNotifyHandler.sendMessage(mNotifyHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_NOTIFY_GET_CATEGORY_DONE));
    }
}
private Handler mNotifyHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        switch (msg.what){
            case MESSAGE_NOTIFY_GET_CATEGORY_DONE:
                if(mOnModelTaskDone != null){
                    Log.e("dj","Fire event update category list");
                    mOnModelTaskDone.onGetListCategoryDone(DjModel.getInstance(null).getListCategory());
                }
                break;
        }

    }
};
}
```

Everything run OK at the first time I open app. But when I press the Back button, I got this on the logcat:

```
01-14 00:02:25.810  16917-16917/tn.han.app.djvip E/ActivityThread﹕ Activity tn.han.app.djvip.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection tn.han.app.djvip.MainActivity$1@2f0816c9 that was originally bound here
android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity tn.han.app.djvip.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection tn.han.app.djvip.MainActivity$1@2f0816c9 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1072)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:966)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1768)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1751)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:538)
        at tn.han.app.djvip.MainActivity.onGetListCategoryDone(MainActivity.java:630)
        at tn.han.app.djvip.model.DjModel$1.handleMessage(DjModel.java:336)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

(DjModel.java:336) is:

```
mOnModelTaskDone.onGetListCategoryDone(DjModel.getInstance(null).getListCategory());
```

(MainActivity.java:630) is:

```
bindService(mDownloadIntent, mDownloadServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

I don't know why the onGetListCategoryDone still fire  even I didn't call the doDownloadCategoryList()...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues going on. First, the thread is not lifecycle aware, so when your activity is dismissed the thread continues to run. You must stop it and cancel work in your activity's `onPause`. Second, you are starting a `Service` which gives you a `Binder` but you are not calling `unbindService` when your activity is destroyed, so the logcat shows the message about the leaked connection.

To clarify the last point: the logcat is showing the problem as a `ServiceConnection` not being unbound.  That's really the source of the problem here.  The stack trace in the logcat output isn't showing where the crash is occurring, but rather *where the `bindService()` call was made* to assist you with tracking down the exact `ServiceConnection` object which needs to be provided in an `unbindService()` call when the `Activity` is paused/stopped/destroyed.

Comment: Incase thread continues to run, why onGetListCategoryDone still be call? I didn't call the doDownloadCategoryList so why it's still call? I'm stuck in it. By the way, you said that I must stop and cancel work, what should I do?

Comment: The `Activity` code is calling `doDownloadCategoryList()`.  It's one of the things it does in its `onCreate()`.  This causes the thread to run and when it finishes it is sending a `Message` to a `Handler` which is bound to the main thread of your app and that in turn calls `bindServce()`.  To fix it, your `Activity` will need to maintain a reference to the running `Thread` and stop it when it is exiting.  `AsyncTask` is available for just this purpose, but can cause similar problems if you're not careful.  This article may help: http://po.st/Cei3m2

Comment: So you mean the onCreate call twice? I do a small test like this: after call the onGetListCategoryDone I set the  mOnModelTaskDone to null, then when I press back button. the logcat still show error when fire the onGetListCategoryDone, why??? I think problem don't place at how I stop or cancel thread, because it's just run when I call doDownloadCategory...hmmm Very strange!!!

Comment: No, `onCreate()` is called when the `Activity` is created, which starts your thread.  When the thread finishes it posts to the `Handler` which in turn calls through `mOnModelTaskDone`.  You're seeing a race condition where the thread is finishing before you pressed back.  If you did manage to `null` it out, you'd then see a `NullPointerException` because the message handler is calling through directly.

Comment: Also note that the `Activity` being destroyed is not the same as the `Application` being exited.  Android doesn't work like that.  The app's process sticks around and is cached and the different components have separate lifecycles.

Comment: So what is the solution? The thread is not loopable and as I said, when I set null to the mOnModelTaskDone to null but it's still going on even I've a condition like if(mOnModelTaskDone != null)! Did you see that is very strange?

Comment: Where do you set it to null? The best advice I can give you on this is not to unnecessarily use singletons and track your running threads so you can cancel them appropriately when the activity stops.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68781/discussion-between-han-tran-and-larry-schiefer).